# How do I compile inline assembly using x64 architecture with visual studio 2012?

Tags: c++, assembly, inline

I'm trying to compile an inline assembly code which works fine with x86 but as I learned you cannot compile inline assembly code with x64. Is there a work around for this? Any help appreciated. The code segment that I use _asm:

```
int vfscanf(FILE* file, const char *format, va_list argPtr)
{
    size_t count = 0;
    const char* p = format;

    while(1)
    {
        char c = *(p++);
        if (c == 0) 
            break;

        if (c == '%' && (p[0] != '*' && p[0] != '%')) 
            ++count;
    }

    if (count <= 0)
        return 0;

    int result;

    _asm
    {
        mov esi, esp;
    }

    for (int i = count - 1; i >= 0; --i)
    {
        _asm
        {
            mov eax, dword ptr[i];
            mov ecx, dword ptr [argPtr];
            mov edx, dword ptr [ecx+eax*4];
            push edx;
        }
    }

    int stackAdvance = (2 + count) * 4;

    _asm
    {
        mov eax, dword ptr [format];
        push eax;
        mov eax, dword ptr [file];
        push eax;

        call dword ptr [fscanf];

        mov result, eax;
        mov eax, dword ptr[stackAdvance];
        add esp, eax;
    }

    return result;
}
```

The code segment that I call this function:

```
int scan(const char * _Format, ... )
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, _Format);
    _interlockedbittestandset()
    int result = vfscanf(_ptr, _Format, args);
    va_end(args);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Basically, you don't. Inline assembler is not supported in Visual studio for 64-bit. Either use out of line assembler, or use C/C++ code - perhaps with use of intrinsic functions if necessary.

Comment: _interlockedbittestandset I've found that intrinsic function is the function that I should use to fix my code. But I couldn't find out how to use it. If you provide me an example for this function it would be great. Thank you for your help. @MatsPetersson

Comment: I would need to know what you are actually trying to to... Probably something like `if (_interlockedbittestandset(&somevar, 3)) ...` - but it's a little hard to say for sure without specifics.

Comment: @MatsPetersson I'm trying to implement vfscanf function to the visual studio 2012 which doesn't support the vfscanf function. By doing that I'm supposed to be able to wrap fscanf function. I'll edit my question and try to provide some more details.

Comment: How about upgrading to VS 2013 or later (which has vfscanf)? The "where I call this" doesn't really make much sense with regards to using interlockedbittestandset, why do you [think you] need that? - why not just make a macro that inserts the `_ptr` in calls to `scan`?

Comment: @MatsPetersson I'm an intern at a company which uses vs2012 on all of its computers so it looks impossible for me to upgrade the compiler. What do you mean by making a macro that inserts the _ptr I couldn't understand that I'm sorry. I thank you so much for your interest.

Comment: Well, I'm guessing that if you are trying to do something in 64-bit that you previously did in 32-bit, then you are changing what your development is doing quite dramatically. I don't think upgrading the compiler is such a big step at that point...

Comment: @MatsPetersson Well not a big step for me but I don't think company would upgrade their compilers just for me. Thanks for your help, I think I have to find another workaround for this problem.